# How to show price(including tax) in the basket page?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart

In my cart page (i.e checkout/cart.phtml) each added product with price and total product price(**subtotal**) is shown as following...

```
<div class="cart contpdng">
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table" width="98%" align="right">
            <tbody>
            <?php 
                foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="subtotal-before-delivery">
                    <td class="txtRight">SUBTOTAL : </td>
                    <td>
                    <?php 
                        $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals(); 
                        $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($totals["subtotal"]->getValue(), true, false);
                        echo $formattedPrice;  ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl()."checkout/cart/login"; ?>" name=" " title="<?php echo $this->__('Secure Checkout'); ?>" class="button btnPrimary" id=""><?php echo $this->__('Secure Checkout'); ?></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>" name=" " title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping'); ?>" class="button" id=""><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping'); ?></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The below code shows the product image and its price(excluding tax), But I want to show the price(including tax)  .

```
<?php 
     foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
         <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Then the below code shows the total price (excluding vat) of the added products in the cart.

```
<?php 
     $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals(); 
     $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($totals["subtotal"]->getValue(), true, false);
     echo $formattedPrice;  
?>
```

I want to display all the price (i.e each product and also "SUBTOTAL") inlcuding tax in the cart page.
How can I get the price (including tax) in the cart page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
<?php
    $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
    $_taxHelper  = $this->helper('tax');
    $priceIncTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice(), true);
    $priceIncTax = Mage::helper('core')->currency(number_format($priceIncTax ,2)); 
?>
<?php echo $priceIncTax; ?> inc. VAT
```

Comment: I have modified my question. Please look into this.